# Get coordinates of showsUserLocation marker in react-native-maps for Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Does anyone know how to get the coordinates of the showsUserLocation-marker in react-native-maps? Or how to modify the Java code for Android to extract this information?

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Started looking at the same thing myself. Found "react-native-android-map-view" and "FusedLocationProviderApi" to be promising ways to introduce location-notifiers from RN-maps. Ended up using the not ideal workaround `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`, as my time does not seem to be infinite. Used it for map-following and path-drawing.

Comment: @mcmhav I see. Trying to avoid using the navigator.geolocation as it is really unstable on android. But I think I'll be able to implement the coordinates as a callback in the existing library (like onRegionChange, for example). Was just hoping someone else had done it before me.

Comment: @mcmhav how do you do the path-drawing? I'm trying to build the same thing with google direction API with mode='walking' but it is not accurate at all

Comment: 1. Fetch the coords as suggested by @J.Doe (I found that `20` meter was an ok value for `distanceFilter`, as too many seemed to get troublesome for `react-native-maps`. But you might end up cutting some corners)
2. Adding these to a storage as you get them (e.g. redux-store)
3. In the component visualising the map and path, `MapView.Polyline` was used to draw the lines between the coords. `{coords.map(coord => <MapView.Polyline coordinates={coords} />)}`
This gave a fairly good walk-path.

Comment: navigator.geolocation.watchPosition is not matching with showuserlocation of react-native-map, as I move useraloacation moves perfectly, but I get the data from geolocation not accurately. any idea how to achieve the value of showuserlocation.onregionChange and onRegionComplete it only works when we touch the screen

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it, in order to obtain true real time GPS data, you need to specify your third party parameter, distanceFilter

```
const GEOLOCATION_SETTINGS = { enableHighAccuracy: true, distanceFilter: 1, maximumAge: 1000 }
```

Then

```
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    console.log(position.coords) // get your showUserLocation here
},
  (error) => console.log(error.message), GEOLOCATION_SETTINGS
)
```